# Repeat the Max count of LEAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY))

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, db2-luw

How can I rewrite the sql below to repeat the max number of count for each group Like the picture as Desired Result column?

```
LEAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY GP, DATEDIFF  ORDER BY  YRMO ASC), 12) AS ACTIVE_MOS
```

[image]

```html
GP  YRMO    DATEDIFF    ACTIVE_MOS  DESIRED RESULT
54  202012  0   1   12
54  202101  0   2   12
54  202102  0   3   12
54  202103  0   4   12
54  202104  0   5   12
54  202105  0   6   12
54  202106  0   7   12
54  202107  0   8   12
54  202108  0   9   12
54  202109  0   10  12
54  202110  0   11  12
54  202111  0   12  12
54  202112  0   12  12
54  202201  0   12  12
54  202202  0   12  12
54  202203  0   12  12
54  202204  0   12  12
54  202205  0   12  12
54  202206  0   12  12
54  202207  0   12  12
54  202208  0   12  12
54  202209  0   12  12
54  202210  0   12  12
54  202211  0   12  12
54  202310  1   1   4
54  202311  1   2   4
54  202312  1   3   4
54  202401  1   4   4
```

Comment: `MAX (ACTIVE_MOS) OVER (PARTITION BY GP, DATEDIFF) AS DESIRED_RESULT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
WITH T (GP, YRMO, DATEDIFF) AS
(
VALUES
  (54, 202012, 0)
, (54, 202101, 0)
, (54, 202102, 0)
, (54, 202103, 0)
, (54, 202104, 0)
, (54, 202105, 0)
, (54, 202106, 0)
, (54, 202107, 0)
, (54, 202108, 0)
, (54, 202109, 0)
, (54, 202110, 0)
, (54, 202111, 0)
, (54, 202112, 0)
, (54, 202201, 0)
, (54, 202202, 0)
, (54, 202203, 0)
, (54, 202204, 0)
, (54, 202205, 0)
, (54, 202206, 0)
, (54, 202207, 0)
, (54, 202208, 0)
, (54, 202209, 0)
, (54, 202210, 0)
, (54, 202211, 0)
, (54, 202310, 1)
, (54, 202311, 1)
, (54, 202312, 1)
, (54, 202401, 1)
)
SELECT 
  T.*
, MAX (ACTIVE_MOS) OVER (PARTITION BY GP, DATEDIFF) AS DESIRED_RESULT
FROM
(
SELECT 
  T.*
, LEAST (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY GP, DATEDIFF  ORDER BY  YRMO ASC), 12) AS ACTIVE_MOS 
FROM T
) T
```

| GP | YRMO | DATEDIFF | ACTIVE_MOS | DESIRED_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 202012 | 0 | 1 | 12 |
| 54 | 202101 | 0 | 2 | 12 |
| 54 | 202102 | 0 | 3 | 12 |
| 54 | 202103 | 0 | 4 | 12 |
| 54 | 202104 | 0 | 5 | 12 |
| 54 | 202105 | 0 | 6 | 12 |
| 54 | 202106 | 0 | 7 | 12 |
| 54 | 202107 | 0 | 8 | 12 |
| 54 | 202108 | 0 | 9 | 12 |
| 54 | 202109 | 0 | 10 | 12 |
| 54 | 202110 | 0 | 11 | 12 |
| 54 | 202111 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202112 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202201 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202202 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202203 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202204 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202205 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202206 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202207 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202208 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202209 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202210 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202211 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 54 | 202310 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 54 | 202311 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 54 | 202312 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 54 | 202401 | 1 | 4 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ExlNaLk6)

Note, that you may omit the subselect in DB2 for LUW (but not in DB2 for IBM i), if you don't need the `ACTIVE_MOS` column in the result with the following expression.

```
MAX 
(
  LEAST (DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY GP, DATEDIFF  ORDER BY  YRMO ASC), 12)
) OVER (PARTITION BY GP, DATEDIFF) AS DESIRED_RESULT
```

Comment: Yes Max(Least()) was not working for it! Thank you very much!